# Filter out specific json array fields of elements using jq

Tags: json, jq, aws-cli

I run a `aws rds describe-instances` and I got a `json` array of the instances more or less as follows:

```
"DBInstances": [
        {
            "DBInstanceIdentifier": "my-rds",
            "Endpoint": {
                "HostedZoneId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "DBSecurityGroups": [],
            "VpcSecurityGroups": [
                {
                    "VpcSecurityGroupId": "sg-12345",
                    "Status": "active"
                },
                {
                    "VpcSecurityGroupId": "sg-12345",
                    "Status": "active"
                }
            ],
            "DBParameterGroups": [
                {
                    "DBParameterGroupName": "postgres-12",
                    "ParameterApplyStatus": "in-sync"
                }
            ],
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-1c",
            "DBSubnetGroup": {
                "VpcId": "vpc-123456",
                "SubnetGroupStatus": "Complete",
                "Subnets": [
                    {
                        "SubnetIdentifier": "subnet-123456",
                        "SubnetAvailabilityZone": {
                            "Name": "us-west-1b"
                        },
                        "SubnetOutpost": {},
                        "SubnetStatus": "Active"
                    },
                    {
                        "SubnetIdentifier": "subnet-12345",
                        "SubnetAvailabilityZone": {
                            "Name": "us-west-1c"
                        },
                        "SubnetOutpost": {},
                        "SubnetStatus": "Active"
                    },
                    {
                        "SubnetIdentifier": "subnet-12345",
                        "SubnetAvailabilityZone": {
                            "Name": "us-west-1e"
                        },
                        "SubnetOutpost": {},
                        "SubnetStatus": "Active"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "EngineVersion": "11.9",
            "AutoMinorVersionUpgrade": true,
            "ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifiers": [],
            "LicenseModel": "foobar",
            "OptionGroupMemberships": [
                {
                    "OptionGroupName": "randomname",
                    "Status": "in-sync"
                }
            ],
        },
    }
```

output truncated obviously.

Is there a way using (`jq` probably?) to print:

a) all elements of the `DBInstances` array

and for each element print only

b) the `DBInstanceIdentifier` and the `EngineVersion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following JQ filter:

```
.DBInstances[] | [ .DBInstanceIdentifier, .EngineVersion ]
```

Where

- `.DBInstances[]` Loops over the `DBInstances` array
- `[ .DBInstanceIdentifier, .EngineVersion ]` creates an array containing only the `DBInstanceIdentifier` and `EngineVersion` keys

```sh
jq '.DBInstances[] | [ .DBInstanceIdentifier, .EngineVersion ]'
```

###### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vTrrpYXjfO)

---

As of your current JSON Example (with only 1 item in the `DBInstances` Array) the result is:

```
[
  "my-rds",
  "11.9"
]
```

Comment: That produces a stream of JSON documents. If you want JSON instead, use `.DBInstances | map([ .DBInstanceIdentifier, .EngineVersion ])`

Answer (score 1):

Solved, not with `.jq`,  but with an `aws` cli feature:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --query 'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier, EngineVersion]'
```